# Chrome extension API to manipulate other installed Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension that needs to do a lot of things with other extensions, such as:

- List installed extensions and read their IDs
- Request extension installation, update and removal (preferably without bothering the user)
- Modify extension settings

and so on. Which of these are possible, and which are not (due to e.g. security considerations)?

P.S. I haven't been able to find answers in the inter-extension messaging section of the official docs (or anywhere else, actually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromium developer Brian Kennish states [here](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/a98f2931370381ec?hl=en) suggests writing an NPAPI plugin as the most rational option to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: How about this? You can do some stuff.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html

Comment: Thanks, Mohamed. This particular subset of the API seems to be quite new (it was unavailable when I asked the question). Still, I no longer need it, because I was planning to write an extension that would manage extension sync across Chrome installations, and that functionality has since already made its way into Chrome itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can do most of those things today with [chrome.management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html). For example:

Get a list of information about installed extensions and apps:

```
chrome.management.getAll(function callback)
```

Uninstall a currently installed app or extension:

```
chrome.management.uninstall(string id, object options, function callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible via the extension API.  To be honest, I wouldn't recommend using NPAPI for this either since you'd have to modify files which are in-use by the browser, which is unreliable at best.